# How to calibrate a camera and a robot

Tags: computer-vision, camera, camera-calibration, robotics

I have a robot and a camera. The robot is just a 3D printer where I changed the extruder for a tool, so it doesn't print but it moves every axis independently. The bed is transparent, and below the bed there is a camera, the camera never moves. It is just a normal webcam (playstation eye).

I want to calibrate the robot and the camera, so that when I click on a pixel on a image provided by the camera, the robot will go there. I know I can measure the translation and the rotation between the two frames, but that will probably return lots of errors.

So that's my question, how can I relate the camera and a robot. The camera is already calibrated using chessboards.

In order to make everything easier, the Z-axis can be ignored. So the calibration will be over X and Y.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of what error is acceptable for you.

We have similar setup where we have camera which looks at some plane with object on it that can be moved.

We assume that the image and plane are parallel.

First lets calculate the rotation. Put the tool in such position that you see it on the center of the image, move it on one axis select the point on the image that is corresponding to tool position.
Those two points will give you a vector in the image coordinate system.
The angle between this vector and original image axis will give the rotation.

The scale may be calculated in the similar way, knowing the vector length (in pixels) and the distance between the tool positions(in mm or cm) will give you the scale factor between the image and real world axis.

If this method won't provide enough accuracy you may calibrate the camera for distortion and relative position to the plane using computer vision techniques. Which is more complicated.
See the following links

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut10.html

Comment: I calibrated the image because the distortion was very high.

Then I used a relation between camera points and tool real world point (all in 2D) to compute the transformation matrix (one rotation, one translation over x and one over y).

But I have problems to calculate the translations. I can do it by hand, but... it's very error prone.

Comment: Basically you have to identify some point whith know coordinates in the tool system on the image, you can place some marker or select the point by yourself, while I can't see your setup it is quite difficult to explain the procedure exactly

Comment: THis is the robot:
http://youtu.be/YZnsBhWDvFI

The tool is the tip of the needle.

You can also see the camera and the image from the camera. My objective is to click over some pixel in that image from the camera, and have the needle moved there.

I places the needle in that image over 10 different places and I let the user click on the pixel where the needle is. Then I use "findhomography" from OpenCV to find the relation, the translation is very good, the rotation isn't, so there is a huge difference between where the needle goes and where it should be

Comment: @MichaelKupchick both links are dead